# Defining const outside React component to read from window

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component and a few helper methods in a `tsx` file. I want to initialize some data from the `global` window object.

The HTML has a `script` tag inside `head` intializing data like shown below:

```
<head>
  <script>
      (function(global) {
        'use strict';
        global["my-app"] = {};
        global["my-app"]["data"] = {
          key1 : 'value1',
          ....
        }
    })(window);
  </script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
```

Some fields from the global data are used inside the React component and in the functions as well. If I read from the window object and initialize inside the React component, then I have to pass the fields (a, b, c, d) to the individual methods.

```
import React from "react";
//other imports

const function1 = (a, b) => {
  //uses a, b
}

const function2 = (a, d) => {
  //uses a, d
}

export default function MyComponent(props: Props) {
    const {a, b, c, d} = window["my-app"]["data"]
    

    function f() {
        //uses a and c 
        console.log(a + c);

        //passes to other functions
        function1(a, b)
        ...
        function2(a, d)     
    }
}
```

Instead, can I move it outside the React component so that it will be available to the component as well as the helper functions like,

```
import React from "react";
//other imports

const {a, b, c, d} = window["my-app"]["data"]; //moved outside the component

const function1 = () => {
  //uses a, b
}

const function2 = () => {
  //uses a, d
}

export default function MyComponent(props: Props) {
    //uses a, b and c

    function f() {
        //uses a and c 
        console.log(a + c);

        function1()
        ...
        function2()     
    }
}
```

I've tested this and this is working. But, will it properly be initialized all the time if I move it outside the component? Would `window["my-app"]["data"]` be available when this is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have got specific reason for initializing that data in the head, but usually we do it with 3rd party libraries like initializing analytics and stuff. But if you want global data access across the app, `React` provides solution for this in the form of `Context` or any other state management library like `Redux`.

It is not recommended in general to populate the `window` object for several reasons but am not gonna go in details.

With your current implementation, if the data in the window object is subject to change, it won't re-render any of the component which is consuming that piece of data from `window`, it only happens if state or prop changes which not the case in your example right now.

So coming back to your question, YES it should be readily available outside your component or where in your app you access it, but as general practice you should avoid it as a whole.

Comment: The global data is set by backend (jsp) and I can stick to that as of now and I don't have a need to re-render as they won't change